# Junit5 Testing library not recognized by IntelliJ Ultimate Edition

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I am trying to create a Java project with Junit5 tests in IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.1 (Ultimate Edition).

Java version: Corretto-11.0.19.7.1

Following is my project structure

```
myJavaProject/
├── build.gradle.kts
├── gradle
│   └── wrapper
│       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
│       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
├── settings.gradle.kts
└── src
    ├── main
    │   ├── java
    │   │   └── org
    │   │       └── example
    │   │           └── Main.java
    │   └── resources
    └── test
        ├── java
        │   └── org
        │       └── example
        └── resources
```

Following is my `build.gradle.kts` file

```
plugins {
    id("java")
}

group = "org.example"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.9.2")
}


tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    systemProperty("junit.jupiter.conditions.deactivate", "*")
    systemProperty("junit.jupiter.extensions.autodetection.enabled", true)
    systemProperty("junit.jupiter.testinstance.lifecycle.default", "per_class")
}
```

I am trying to create a test for Main.java file as shown here - https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/create-tests.html

When creating a test through UI, I don't see Junit5 as one of the option in the drop down menu. I verified that the correct directories are marked TestSourcesRoot, SourcesRoot, Resources Root and Test Resources Root.

I am stuck with this issue for a while. Any help is appreciated. Please let me know if you need more info. from my side.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Intellij without Junit PLugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oinzp.png)

If you are only receiving the options as shown in the image while creating a test class through UI, your IntelliJ does not have the Junit plugin, or its in a disabled state.

[INtellij Junit plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vr26M.png)

If you enable the junit plugin. it will give you Junit, Junit5 options in UI

Comment: Gutter Icons show up now as well. I wasted a lot of time on this. Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

The API is manifest with junit-jupiter-api.
The runtime is junit-jupiter-engine for JUnit 5, and junit-vintage-engine for JUnit 3 or 4.

We supply these two in test Implementation and timeRuntimeOnly, respectively:

```
dependencies {
testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1'
testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1'
}
```

You've only added one dependency

Comment: Adding the Junit plugin to IntellIJ resolved the issue for me.